# Why is there a strange grey border on the top and right edges of my screen in GNOME?

Tags: gnome

I have recently noticed that there is a grey border the same colour as the GNOME login screen background which is about 1 or 2 pixels thick and goes on the top and right edge of my screen as can be seen in this screenshot (I edited it in GIMP so that all but the grey has been turned to white so you should be able to see the grey border):

[image: Desktop with strange border]

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20, I only noticed this a few days ago though I don't know how long it's been there for as it's not completely noticeable immediately. But why could this be? And is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Is this on a external desktop monitor that has menu controls that allow you to set the horizontal/vertical size, and the horizontal/vertical positioning of the desktop? If so, then maybe there's also an auto-calibrate that you can also try. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema: Nope, this is my primary laptop built-in monitor.